# Inner Frame Mounted Carrying Bag

Tags: cargo, bags

I've been thinking for awhile that having a bag on the inside of the frame of the bike would be a good place to store a few small things, such as a camelback bladder, shirt, etc. What I mean is a bag mounted where [the yellow triangle is in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8T7B.png). For all I know, it's a common thing in bike shops, but I haven't been to one in a few years (unless you count Canadian Tire) and I've never seen anyone with something like it.

Would it be a good idea? Does it exist? If so, where could I get one?

Comment: Any special needs? There are hundreds to be [found in the internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=bike+frame+bag&hl=en&tbm=shop).

Comment: @Czechnology Mostly just to carry a change of clothing in, or a camelbak bladder, without having to carry a backpack and get my back quite sweaty. Thanks for the link, quite helpful.

Comment: I have made one at home with very good results. The only downside is that those bags destroy the painting very quickly (which might or not be an important problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many available.  Here is one example: http://www.ebikestop.com/axiom_cascade_frame_pack_black-BG6638.php

Attaches to the seat tube and the top tube, providing a triangular storage space.  This one also is padded to aid with portaging (if you have a big enough triangle).

I know some people who tour with home-made frame bags that take up the entire triangle.

These bags are a great idea because they keep your load close to your center of gravity.

Comment: Went into a couple bike shops around here, and they're sold out at the moment, but should be getting some in soon. In the mean time, I picked up a small one to keep lights and a hat in.

Comment: these bags are great for full-suspension bikes, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Custom Frame Bags](http://www.revelatedesigns.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=store.catalog&CategoryID=1&ProductID=6) from [Revelate Designs](http://www.revelatedesigns.com/).

> Custom made frame bags for your bike. Any size, any shape.

[Bag gallery link](http://www.revelatedesigns.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=gallery.gallery&Categoryid=5)

I haven't tested them (yet) but seems like a very good choice if you're looking for something durable!